# Exception trying to parse date time "02-APR-18 09.26.21" in Java

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to parse a non-standard datetime format in Java 8. I have read the javadoc for the class and AFAICT, I'm providing the format in the correct way.

```
System.out.println(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss", Locale.US)
        .parse("02-APR-18 09.26.21"));
```

but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '02-APR-18 09.26.21' could not be parsed at index 3
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1988)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1816)
```

I have also tried with removing the Locale.US but get exactly the same error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try with 02-Apr-18 09.26.21

Comment: @Musaddique It works with "Apr" but not with "APR". Is there no way in Java to parse an upper case month abbreviation?

Comment: @JoeC You are right, this is a duplicate. I will close it.

Comment: How come it's duplicate?

Comment: @MS90 It's a duplicate because the issue is that the month string was uppercase. The linked question describes how to make a case-insensitive formatter.